# BLE Services never discovered

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to send a message to a BLE device. In my understanding one first has to discover the devices services and then send the message to a service characteristic. So here is what I did:

```
public class BluetoothLeService extends Service {

private BluetoothManager mBluetoothManager;
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private String mBluetoothDeviceAddress;
private BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt;

private String macAddress;
private String serviceUuid;
private String characteristicUuid;
private Application app;
private int transmissionValue = 450;     

public BluetoothLeService(String address, String serviceUuid, String characteristicUuid) {
    this.macAddress = address;
    this.serviceUuid = serviceUuid;
    this.characteristicUuid = characteristicUuid;
}


private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        System.out.println("connectionStateChange: " + status);
        if (STATE_CONNECTED == newState) {
            gatt.discoverServices();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        if(gatt.getDevice().getName().equals("MyDeviceName")) {
            sendMessageAfterDiscovery(gatt);
        }
    }

};

public boolean initialize(Application app) {
    this.app = app;
    if (mBluetoothManager == null) {
        mBluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) app.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        if (mBluetoothManager == null) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    mBluetoothAdapter = mBluetoothManager.getAdapter();
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


public boolean connect() {
    return connect(macAddress);
}

public boolean connect(final String address) {
    this.macAddress = address;
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || macAddress == null) {
        return false;
    }

    final BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(macAddress);
    if (device == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Device not found.  Unable to connect.");
        return false;
    }
    mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);
    return true;
}

public void writeCharacteristic(int value) {
    this.transmissionValue = value;
    BluetoothDevice mDevice = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(this.macAddress);
    BluetoothGatt mBG = mDevice.connectGatt(app.getApplicationContext(), true, mGattCallback);
    System.out.println("device name: " + mBG.getDevice().getName());

}

private void sendMessageAfterDiscovery(BluetoothGatt gatt) {
    BluetoothGattService mSVC = gatt.getService(UUID.fromString(serviceUuid));

    BluetoothGattCharacteristic mCH = mSVC.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString(characteristicUuid));
    mCH.setValue(transmissionValue, BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT16, 0);
    System.out.println("characteristic writable: " + isCharacteristicWriteable(mCH));

    System.out.println("success? " + gatt.writeCharacteristic(mCH));
}

public static boolean isCharacteristicWriteable(BluetoothGattCharacteristic pChar) {
    return (pChar.getProperties() & (BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE_NO_RESPONSE)) != 0;
}
```

}

And here is the code where I want to send the message:

```
private void sendMessage() {
    BluetoothLeService ble = new BluetoothLeService("B0:00:00:00:00:C0", "0000fff0-1111-0000-0000-00805f9b34fb","0000fff1-1111-0000-0000-00805f9b34fb");
    ble.initialize(app);
    ble.connect();,
    ble.writeCharacteristic(450)
 }
```

Now whenever I want to connect to the device and send a message to it, the onServiceDiscovered method is never called although the device is recognized because I can get the name of the device. Also no error is thrown.

Why is this method never called? Am I doing something wrong?
I already checked the permissions and I added the class as a Service in the manifest.

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [`discoverServices`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html#discoverServices()) from within the `onConnectionStateChange` method of your GATT callback. Documentation of the `discoverServices` method:

> Discovers services offered by a remote device as well as their
>   characteristics and descriptors.
>
> This is an asynchronous operation. Once service discovery is
>   completed, the `onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt, int)` callback is
>   triggered. If the discovery was successful, the remote services can be
>   retrieved using the `getServices()` function.

In your case, updating your code as follows should do the trick:

```
@Override
public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
    System.out.println("connectionStateChange: " + status);

    if (STATE_CONNECTED == newState) {
        gatt.discoverServices();
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried that; 
but when I call it in onConnectionStateChange, this method is never called, but I still get the deviceName after the connectGatt;

I updated the code

Comment: Have you verified that the connection state is coming back as `STATE_CONNECTED`?

Comment: The onConnectionStateChange is never called; so there is no connection state to check.

Comment: okay sorry my bad; I forgot to call connect mBG.connect();

now connection State 0 comes back but no success

Comment: If connection fails then it may be that the device you're attempting to connect to is unreachable, but that's outside the scope of this question.